# Restkit mapping while using managedObjectCache

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am mapping a large data set to Core data using Restkit. I am making a call to get data from a web service, storing it in core data and then displaying it from core data. 
Here is my code.

```
+(void) setupManagedObjectStore
{
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];  
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = RKEnsureDirectoryExistsAtPath(RKApplicationDataDirectory(), &error);   
    if (! success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create Application Data Directory at path '%@': %@", RKApplicationDataDirectory(), error);
    }

    NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.sqlite"];

    //Does lightweight migration automatically
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                          NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                          };   
    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [store addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:options error:&error]; 
    if (! persistentStore)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed adding persistent store at path '%@': %@", path, error);
     } 
    [store createManagedObjectContexts];   
    store.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setManagedObjectStore:store];
}
```

Get data, deletes existing data in the table and adds new data

```
-(void)getData:(SuccessBlock)successBlock withFailure:(FailureBlock)failureBlock objectId:(NSString *) objectId
{
    [self deleteData:objectId]; //Deletes the data from the entity
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getData/%@",objectId];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
                                              NSLog(@"SUCCESS in getting data");
                                              if(successBlock){
                                                  successBlock([self getDataFromCoreData:objectId]);
                                              }

                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                              NSLog(@"FAILURE in getting data");                                          

                                          }
 ];    
}

-(NSArray *)getDataFromCoreData : objectId
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId= %@", objectId];

    NSError *error;
    array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return array;
}
```

My core data model has lots of 1:many relationships, and my Restkit mapping was quite slow, hence to improve the performance I added the line

```
store.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

That did improve the performance, but after the deleteData() call, Restkit mapping seems to happen alternately.

Call getData - 1: getDataFromCoreData returns data
Call getData - 2: getDataFromCoreData returns empty array, the table is empty
Call getData - 3: getDataFromCoreData returns data
Call getData - 4: getDataFromCoreData returns empty array, the table is empty

If I comment out the store.managedObjectCache line, everything works fine, and getDataFromCoreData always returns data. But Restkit mapping becomes super slow.
I can't find enough documentation on RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache to understand what exactly is going on..

Can someone help me understand why it would work this way? Or maybe suggest a better way to improve Restkit mapping performance?

EDIT: Adding delete code

```
-(void)deleteData : objectId
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
    NSArray *array = [self getDataFromCoreData: objectId];
    for (NSManagedObject *product in array)
    {      
        [context deleteObject:product];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the delete method and your mapping code

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to do a saveToPersistentStore after the deleteData method call.

I am using persistentStoreManagedObjectContext for the managedObjectCache and mainQueueManagedObjectContext for saving to core data and retrieval.
[persistentStoreManagedObjectContext vs mainQueueManagedObjectContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457290/persistentstoremanagedobjectcontext-vs-mainqueuemanagedobjectcontext)

So saving the context by using saveToPersistentStore, after deleting and before making the web service call fixed the problem.